# Function App, Entity Framework, .Net 6 and environment variables

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

When updating an Azure Functions application that is using Entity Framework (code first) to .Net 6, none of the values from local.settings.json are found. This problem appears when running an "ef" command, but not when debugging or running the application.

The Azure Functions application is configured to run in isolated mode, and retrieves values from the settings file with the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` method. And this works perfect when debugging or running the application.

```cs
// Simplified code example
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
      var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");
      // connectionString is null here only when running dotnet ef command
    });
  builder.RunAsync();
}
```

But if I run any ef command from the terminal (such as `dotnet ef database update`) all values are null so it seems like when running these commands the local.settings.json are not taken in consideration.

This worked fine when running from .Net 5.
The EntityFrameworkCore NuGet packages has of course also been updated to support the new .Net version properly.

---

**Update**

To clarify, the local.settings.json file is simple and structured this way. In .Net 5 I can easily retrieve variables from the "Values" section, but after updating to .Net 6 they are always null when running `dotnet ef` commands.

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "ConnectionString": "[...]"
    },
    "Host": {
        "CORS": "*",
        "CORSCredentials": false
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide your `local.settings.json` to see how you added the values, under the values or connection strings

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I updated the question with what it looks like now.

Comment: provide the logic of how you're trying to access the `local.settings.json`!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I've update the questing with example

Comment: I get the same thing. The environment variables that ef is looking at are the Windows ones and not the ones stored in local.settings.json.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *workaround* that I just got working in a v4 / .NET 7 / Isolated Azure Function App.

Basically, if `local.settings.json` is configured in `.csproj` to `CopyToOutputDirectory`, we can manually bind the `Configuration` and pull in the value from the `values` section.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace MyApp;

public class MyAppDbContextDesignTimeFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyAppDbContext>
{
    public MyAppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
            .Build();
        const string connectionStringKey = "MyAppDbConnectionString";
        var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(connectionStringKey) ??
                               configuration.GetSection("values").GetValue<string>(connectionStringKey) ??
                               throw new InvalidOperationException($"Missing {connectionStringKey}");
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyAppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new MyAppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

I'd still love to see a more official fix for this. [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2183) is related.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different take on this issue. I am totally fine with the connection string being null, as THAT connection string is not needed when running dotnet ef commands.

My reasoning starts from this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations list --no-connect
```

Here I just want to see the migrations I have already added, but I don't care if they have been applied or not, the [--no-connect parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-list) explicitly states that I don't want to connect to the DB => I do not need a connection string!

Yet the previous command would fail with a `The string argument 'connectionString' cannot be empty`

dotnet ef commands will trigger the DI pipeline to be able to "discover" the DbContext and the configuration of your entities: "[If your startup project uses the ASP.NET Core Web Host or .NET Core Generic Host, the tools try to obtain the DbContext object from the application's service provider.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?source=recommendations&tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-application-services)"

> it is desirable that the DbContext thereby created is configured in a
> similar way to how it would be configured at run time.

The connection string being empty is not a problem per se, it becomes a problem because method calls like myOpBuilder.UseSqlServer(someNullString) will complain with `The string argument 'connectionString' cannot be empty`

So the solution that I adopted is this:

```
var dbConStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataBase");

services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(o =>
{
   var isMigration = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("mig");

   if (isMigration)
   {
       o.UseSqlServer();
   }
   else
   {
        o.UseSqlServer(dbConStr);
   }
});
```

and while issuing dotnet ef command I leverage the [CommandLineConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#command-line) and also the [fact that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#aspnet-core-environment):

> The -- token directs dotnet ef to treat everything that follows as an argument and not try to parse them as options. Any extra arguments not used by dotnet ef **are forwarded to the app**.

so I manage to run my dotnet ef commands successfully:

```
dotnet ef migrations list --no-connect -- mig=true
```

In case I really want to hit the db using some dotnet ef command I pass the connection string as an argument to the command with the [--connection parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update).